# React router change use API id (uuidv4) for navigation but show user friendly slug in URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When you define a route in react-router like:

```
path: '/user/:id',
```

You can navigation to `/user/1234567` or `/user/05b19132-2dc2-48c4-987a-e716c300a5f9`. Is it possible to still use the id for navigation because the API needs it for follow up calls to fetch more data but you show the user slug in the URL intead.

Example:
When a user goes to '/user/mr-gamer-1999' it actually uses the id of `mr-gamer-1999` which is `1234567`

User sees: '/user/mr-gamer-1999'
system needs param: 1234567

Comment: This is nothing to do with React Router. If you have a way of mapping from slugs to IDs, just use that. If slugs aren't unique, you're out of luck... though you could do something like `/user/mr-gamer-1999-1234567` and just ignore everything before the last `-` when doing the lookup (this also avoids the problem of stale slugs if users can change their username).

Comment: I have a user: { slug: 'mr-gamer-1999', id:'1234567'} so a slug is related to an id. Both are unique

Comment: OK, so set an index on slugs in your database (or another field such as `username` if slugs are generated from that), then change whatever logic you're using to lookup by ID to lookup by slug instead. It's impossible to help beyond that without seeing your code and what you've tried already.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'd also like to know how to do this

Comment: No the only way you can do this is by using the slug as navigation ID or create a backend endpoint like: fetch_slug_by_id and use the ID to get the slug for navigation.